# Mapping Old URLs to new joomla 2.5 website SEF urls?

Tags: joomla, url-rewriting, sef

I have a weird situation. A client of mine has a website having this kind of URL:

**OLD URL:** website.com/products/the+product_1.php

Now the new website that we developed has joomla 2.5 and has all content in there... So we have enabled Joomla SEF there. Now the issue is how to map the OLD urls to new Urls.

And the new Joomla 2.5 URL Looks like this:

**New URL:** website.com/products/digi/category/the_product_1

Now the issue is the search engines have indexed the OLD URLs and client does not want to loose the Page Ranking as you know how it matters.... They have about 18k URLs.

**How best I can map the Old URLs to new URLs?**

Please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, why didn´t you use the Joomla build in redirection manager?
http://docs.joomla.org/Help17:Components_Redirect_Manager

Sure it takes some time to build the links into it, but from my point of view this would be the best way. Then there is no need to develop something and everything can be managed in joomla.

You can also write a script which add links to the SQL DB if needed for this component.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to [create a system plugin](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin) that looks for the old product URL pattern and fires a redirect to the new URL. You should also look at this [list of new and renamed events](http://docs.joomla.org/What%27s_new_in_Joomla_1.6#Events) as some of them have changed since the plugin documentation was written.